# Android countDownTimer - make millisUntilFinished float

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a timer:

```
CountDownTimer sample = new CountDownTimer() {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
};
```

And I want to make the `millisUntilFinished` to a float.
how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast it

```
float f = (float) millisUntilFinished;
```

but bear in mind that `long` can hold larger values that `float`, so for large values, this won't be possible.